# Recommendations for a visual Wikipedia table editor?

Tags: linux, mediawiki, wikimedia, editor, table

I am looking for a visual Wikipedia table editor that generates the markup code to be placed directly into a Wikipedia page.

**Requirements:**

- Offline support
- Chrome app or native Linux (Ubuntu) app
- Visual table creation that generates Wiki markup code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use LibreOffice with the libreoffice-wiki-publisher package. Create or edit your table in Writer, export to MediaWiki format.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/29469443/1333493